# Showing Metabox for only certain template page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, meta-boxes

I am trying to show a certain metabox only on a certain template. I have tried putting this code in my functions.php file:

```
    add_filter('rwmb_meta_boxes', 'main_page_register_meta_boxes' );

    function main_page_register_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
        $prefix = '';
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    
        $meta_boxes[] = [
            'title'   => esc_html__( 'Header', 'Header' ),
            'id'      => 'Header_section_1',
            'post_types' => ['page'],
            'context'    => 'normal',
            'include' => array(
                'template' => array( 'content-mainPage.php' ),
            ),
            'fields'  => [
                [
                    'type'  => 'text',
                    'name'  => esc_html__( 'title', 'title' ),
                    'id'    => $prefix . 'title',
                    
                ],
                [
                    'type'  => 'wysiwyg',
                    'name'  => esc_html__( 'Description', 'Description' ),
                    'id'    => $prefix . 'Description',
                    
                ],
            ],
        ];
    
       
    
        return $meta_boxes;
    }
```

I found a solution that adds a display condition for a specific page template but it doesn't work in my case

```
'include' => array(
                'template' => array( 'content-mainPage.php' ),
            ),
```

The still created metabox is displayed when editing each page.

Does anyone know how to create a metabox that will be assigned to a specific Wordpress page template?

Comment: What is the filter rwmb_meta_boxes that you are using? I don’t know this filter but apparently it is triggered for every page in the admin. The wordpress function `get_current_screen` can be used inside the function for you to determine whether to show the metabox  or not.

Comment: Or you can use the action `add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_{slug of your post type here}',`.

Comment: I used this generator to create a metabox
https://metabox.io/online-generator/
I would like the metabox to appear or disappear when creating a page after selecting a template

Comment: You should use javascript for that.

Comment: Add an eventlistener to the template changer and show the metabox according to what is selected.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://support.metabox.io/topic/showing-metabox-for-only-certain-template/

Comment: I saw it, but it doesn't work for me, that's why I'm asking for help

Comment: Well, the javascript is relatively simple. Here is how you can add an eventlistener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: For now: try to get the eventlistener to work. Once you have done that, you will see that it is easy to see what has been selected and you can determine what to show and hide on the page depending on what has been selected by your users.